# Why is my cloth having a seizure?

Tags: cloth-simulation

My cloth is doing this, how do i fix it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: to add to Evripidis Lalissidis' answer, it will be lighter to put the Subdivision Surface under the Cloth

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you subdivided the "blanket" and then added a decimate modifier over it.
This brought your face count down to 76, making it very hard for Blender to simulate cloth simulations.

[image]

This is how your mesh looks after the modifiers have been applied. This is what the cloth simulation is trying to animate (simulate).

[image]

Try removing the SubD modifier and the decimate modifier.
If you run into more problems, In the simulation tab, increase the quality of your cloth simulation (but keep in mind that doing so will also increase render time).
Check self-collision as well for accurate results.

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Comment: It would help future users to solve the same problem if you check my answer as the right answer :). Your welcome